# Code returning :.2f as invalid for a str, not sure where I'm missing the Float conversion

Tags: python, string, csv

Working on a code for Python, where essentially I am taking a csv file and depending on user input, I can print/return the connected information within the csv file. Essentially I'm slowly but surely de-bugging it but I'm stuck most likely due to frustration and would love some help catching what's wrong. So been trying to hunt where I should convert to float, if you see it. I'd love any help to see it.

My code:

```
import csv
import sys

from csv import reader

def read_csv(file):
    with open(file, 'r') as read_obj:
        csv_reader = list(csv.reader(read_obj, delimiter= ','))
        return csv_reader
  
def filter_data(user_input, data):
    filtered_data = []
    for row in data:
        if (row[0].lower() == user_input.lower()):
            filtered_data.append(row)
        elif (row[4].lower() == user_input.lower()):
                filtered_data.append(row)
    return filtered_data

def calc_averages(filtered_data):
    lst = [0, 0, 0]
    for row in filtered_data:
        lst[0] += float(row[7])
        lst[1] += float(row[8])
        lst[2] += float(row[9])
    lst[0] = (lst[0]/len(filtered_data))
    lst[1] = (lst[1]/len(filtered_data))
    lst[2] = (lst[2]/len(filtered_data))
    return lst

def calc_minimums(filtered_data):
    min_concentration = filtered_data[0][8]
    min_longevity = filtered_data[0][9]
    min_paralyzed = filtered_data[0][11]
    for line in filtered_data:
        if line[8] < min_concentration:
            min_concentration = line[8]
        if line[9] < min_longevity:
            min_longevity = line[9]
        if line[11] < min_paralyzed:
            min_paralyzed = line[11]
    return [min_concentration, min_longevity, min_paralyzed]

def calc_maximums(filtered_data):
    max_concentration = filtered_data[0][8]
    max_longevity = filtered_data[0][9]
    max_paralyzed = filtered_data[0][11]
    for line in filtered_data:
        if line[8] > max_concentration:
            max_concentration = line[8]
        if line[9] > max_longevity:
            max_longevity = line[9]
        if line[11] > max_paralyzed:
            max_paralyzed = line[11]
    return [max_concentration, max_longevity, max_paralyzed]

def print_stats(user_input, stat_type, stats):
    print (f'{stat_type}s for {user_input} bees:')
    print (f'{stat_type}s for {user_input} bees:')
    print (f'{stat_type} Imidacloprid Concentration: {stats[0]:.2f}')
    print (f'{stat_type} Days Paralyzed: {stats[2]:.2f}\n')

def run(data):
    user_input = input('Enter the species/genus or the sociality of bee you would like information about: ')
    filtered_data = filter_data(user_input, data)
    averages = calc_averages(filtered_data)
    minimums = calc_minimums(filtered_data)
    maximums = calc_maximums(filtered_data)
    print_stats(user_input, 'Average', averages)
    print_stats(user_input, 'Minimum', minimums)
    print_stats(user_input, 'Maximum', maximums)
    more_data = input('Would you like to see more data? (Y/N) ')
    if more_data == 'Y' or more_data == 'y':
        return True
    else:
        return False

def main():
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print('Invalid arguments given')
        return
    data = read_csv(sys.argv[1])
    while run(data):
        continue
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The error with input "solitary \n n":

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 121, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 117, in main
    while run(data):
  File "main.py", line 104, in run
    print_stats(user_input, 'Minimum', minimums)
  File "main.py", line 88, in print_stats
    print (f'{stat_type} Imidacloprid Concentration: {stats[0]:.2f}')
ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'
```

The output is currently:

```
Enter the species/genus or the sociality of bee you would like information about: Averages for solitary bees:
Averages for solitary bees:
Average Imidacloprid Concentration: 29.48
Average Days Paralyzed: 1.33

Minimums for solitary bees:
Minimums for solitary bees:
```

Comment: Strings aren't floats. You're trying to format a _string_ as a float with two decimal places. Maybe convert it to a float first?

Answer (score 1):

Both `calc_minimums` and `calc_maximums` are copying string data directly from the provided `filtered_data` argument without performing any type conversions. It's string data because the `filter_data` function is not performing any type conversions itself, and since you're not reading from the file with the `csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC` flag operating on the `reader`, no type conversion is performed (all the fields in each row are `str`).

It's possible you think you've performed the conversions because you called `float` on the fields in `calc_averages`, but that only *read* from the fields, parsed them, and returned a new `float`, leaving the original `list` unchanged (the values are still `str`).

If you want this to work, do one of:

1. Change `calc_minimums` and `calc_maximums` to perform the same type conversions that `calc_averages` is doing (kind of important, because right now your mins and maxes are based on `str` comparisons, not `float` comparisons, and string lexicographic sorting is almost certainly wrong much of the time, unless all your values have the exact same number of digits)
2. Apply a conversion step to convert the necessary fields to `float` ahead of time, before the data is used (saves repeated conversion work)
3. (If the CSV format supports it) Add the `csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC` to your `csv.reader` creation (assumes all non-numeric fields are in fact quoted, which is unlikely, unless the file was created using the same flag, or comes from an unusual CSV generator)

Assuming #3 isn't an option, the easiest solution (as well as fastest, and least error-prone) is #2; your existing functions don't have to change (the `float` conversions could even be removed from `calc_averages`). Just make a new function, e.g.:

```
# Defaulted arguments match the type and indices your code uses
def convert_data(data, totype=float, convert_indices=(7, 8, 9, 11)):
    '''Modifies data in-place, converting specified indices in each row to totype'''
    for row in data:
        for idx in convert_indices:
            row[idx] = totype(row[idx])
```

Then just add:

```
convert_data(filtered_data)
```

immediately after the line `filtered_data = filter_data(user_input, data)`.

If you prefer not operating in-place, you can make a new `list` with something like this:

```
# Defaulted arguments match the type and indices your code uses
def convert_data(data, totype=float, convert_indices=frozenset({7, 8, 9, 11})):
    '''Returns new copy of data with specified indices in each row converted to totype'''
    convert_indices = frozenset(convert_indices)  # Optimize to reduce cost of
                                                  # checking if index should be converted
    return [[totype(x) if i in convert_indices else x for i, x in enumerate(row)]
            for row in data]
```

and make the inserted line:

```
filtered_data = convert_data(filtered_data)
```